# fails in user acceptance

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 create table Minutes(Minute varchar2(5));
 create table orders(OrderID varchar(54), Orderplaced TIMESTAMP , 
 Ordercompleted TIMESTAMP);
 insert into orders
 VALUES   
 ('#1',TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-15 00:12:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
 TO_TIMESTAMP( '2018-01-15 00:12:42', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
 insert into orders
 VALUES
 ('#2',TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-15 01:15:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
 TO_TIMESTAMP( '2018-01-15 02:56:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
 insert into orders
 VALUES
 ('#3',TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-15 01:20:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
 TO_TIMESTAMP( '2018-01-15 03:00:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

 insert into Minutes (Minute)

 select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' minute * (level - 1), 
 'HH24:MI') as minute
 from dual
 connect by level <= 1440;

 select a.Minute, nvl(count(b.OrderID),0) as orders
 from Minutes a
 left join orders b
 on a.Minute between to_char(cast( b.Orderplaced as date),'hh24:mi:ss')  and 
 to_char(cast( b.Ordercompleted as date),'hh24:mi:ss')
 where
 a.Minute <= (select to_char(cast (sysdate as date),'hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
 group by a.Minute
 order by 1;
```

The processing time is too long and the result is undelivered as well.
 It works fine with Integration testing. Please have a look once.

Comment: What result do you get and what do you expect? Why are you using `between`, and why are you casting? Is it supposed to be finding records on a single day - at the moment it's on any day?

Comment: What about orders that were placed yesterday but completed today (or are not completed yet - so `ordercompleted` date is null)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, works OK for those test tables. However, I'd suggest a slight modification.

- you don't have to CAST values from ORDERS table
- Even *worse* is to CAST SYSDATE AS DATE - SYSDATE is a function that
  returns DATE data type anyway
- there's no need to select it from DUAL - you can use it "as is"
- COUNT will return 0 even if there's nothing to return, so you can
  omit NVL function

Here's the modified SELECT statement:

```
  SELECT a.minute, COUNT (b.orderid) AS orders
    FROM minutes a
         LEFT JOIN orders b
            ON a.minute BETWEEN TO_CHAR (b.orderplaced, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                            AND TO_CHAR (b.ordercompleted, 'hh24:mi:ss')
   WHERE a.minute <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY a.minute
ORDER BY 1;
```

What does it mean for you? I don't know. As I said, it works OK. Explain plan says that it performs full table scan of both MINUTES and ORDERS tables, so - if there's *zillion* rows in those tables, it might make a difference.

Consider creating indexes on columns you use; as you extract only time from the ORDERS table, those two would be function-based ones.

```
CREATE INDEX i1_min
   ON minutes (minute);

CREATE INDEX i2_plac
   ON orders (TO_CHAR (orderplaced, 'hh24:mi:ss'));

CREATE INDEX i3_compl
   ON orders (TO_CHAR (ordercompleted, 'hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Then try again; hopefully, you'll see some improvement.

Comment: Sure, why not? If it turns out that you don't need it, you can always drop it. However, before doing anything, see what your DBA thinks about it.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're trying to get "the number of orders count per minute on a particular day", and later clarified that should be the current day. Your query is only looking at times - converted to strings - so it's looking at the same time slot across all records in your orders table. Really you want to restrict the found orders to the day you're interested in. Presumably your UAT environment just has much more data, across more days, than you created in IT.

You could just add a filter to restrict it to orders placed today:

```
select a.Minute, nvl(count(b.OrderID),0) as orders
from Minutes a
left join orders b
on a.Minute between to_char(cast( b.Orderplaced as date),'hh24:mi:ss')  and 
to_char(cast( b.Ordercompleted as date),'hh24:mi:ss')
and b.Orderplaced > trunc(sysdate) -- added this filter
where
a.Minute <= (select to_char(cast (sysdate as date),'hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
group by a.Minute
order by 1;
```

though you don't need any of the casting or subquery or `nvl()`, as @Littlefoot mentioned, so can simplify that a bit to:

```
select a.Minute, count(b.OrderID) as orders
from Minutes a
left join orders b
on a.Minute between to_char(b.Orderplaced,'hh24:mi:ss')  and 
to_char(b.Ordercompleted,'hh24:mi:ss')
and b.Orderplaced > trunc(sysdate)
where a.Minute <= to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss')
group by a.Minute
order by 1;
```

You're still doing a lot of conversions and comparing strings rather than dates/timestamps. It might be simpler to generate the minutes for that specific day in a CTE instead of a permanent table, and join using those values as well, without doing any further data conversions

```
with minutes (minute) as (
  select cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp) + interval '1' minute * (level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 1440
)
select to_char(m.minute, 'HH24:MI') as minute, count(o.orderid) as orders
from minutes m
left join orders o
on o.orderplaced >= cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp)
and o.orderplaced <= m.minute
and (o.ordercompleted is null or o.ordercompleted >= m.minute)
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

I've included rows with no `ordercompleted` date, though it isn't clear if you want to count those.

You could also join on just the `orderplaced` date being today, which looks a bit odd, and do a conditional count:

```
with minutes (minute) as (
  select cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp) + interval '1' minute * (level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 1440
)
select to_char(m.minute, 'HH24:MI') as minute,
  count(case when o.orderplaced <= m.minute
      and (o.ordercompleted is null or o.ordercompleted >= m.minute)
    then o.orderid end) as orders
from minutes m
left join orders o
on o.orderplaced >= cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp)
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

Either way this assumes you have an index on `orderplaced`.

Look at the execution plans for your original query and these options and any others suggested, and test with realistic data, to see which is the best approach for your actual data and requirements.

---

To look for records for a different, full, day, change the `sysdate` references to a date/timestamp literal like `timestamp '2018-01-15 00:00:00'` or something relative like `trunc(sysdate-1)`, and include an end-date on the `orderplaced`; and remove the end-time filter in the CTE; e.g.:

```
with minutes (minute) as (
  select cast(trunc(sysdate - 1) as timestamp) + interval '1' minute * (level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 1440
)
select to_char(m.minute, 'HH24:MI') as minute, count(o.orderid) as orders
from minutes m
left join orders o
on o.orderplaced >= cast(trunc(sysdate - 1) as timestamp)
and o.orderplaced < cast(trunc(sysdate - 1) as timestamp) + interval '1' day
and o.orderplaced <= m.minute
and (o.ordercompleted is null or o.ordercompleted >= m.minute)
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

or

```
with minutes (minute) as (
  select timestamp '2018-01-15 00:00:00' + interval '1' minute * (level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 1440
)
select to_char(m.minute, 'HH24:MI') as minute, count(o.orderid) as orders
from minutes m
left join orders o
on o.orderplaced >= timestamp '2018-01-15 00:00:00'
and o.orderplaced < timestamp '2018-01-16 00:00:00'
and o.orderplaced <= m.minute
and (o.ordercompleted is null or o.ordercompleted >= m.minute)
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

---

If you want to include rows where the placed and completed times are in the same minute, but still otherwise want to exclude rows from the minute they were placed, you'll need a bit more logic; maybe something like:

```
with minutes (minute) as (
  select timestamp '2018-01-15 00:00:00' + interval '1' minute * (level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 1440
)
select to_char(m.minute, 'HH24:MI') as minute, count(o.orderid) as orders
from minutes m
left join orders o
on o.orderplaced >= timestamp '2018-01-15 00:00:00'
and o.orderplaced < timestamp '2018-01-16 00:00:00'
and ((trunc(o.ordercompleted, 'MI') > trunc(o.orderplaced, 'MI')
    and o.orderplaced <= m.minute)
  or (trunc(o.ordercompleted, 'MI') = trunc(o.orderplaced, 'MI')
    and o.orderplaced < m.minute + interval '1' minute))
and (o.ordercompleted is null or o.ordercompleted >= m.minute)
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

If you need further refinements you'll need to modify the clauses to suit, which might need a bit of experimentation.

Comment: I've made one final edit. You'll need to make any further refinements. (You can probably also delete a lot of the comments now).

Comment: "Fails to work" doesn't tell us anything. Why won't your DBA let you index data if there is a business need for it? Seems like you need to be talking to your DBA about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Then check the execution plans in different environments, see if they are different, and talk to your DBA about why you have to run this and why it needs an index if there isn't one already (or see if they have other solutions).